# Ocean material not visible

Tags: materials, ocean-simulation

following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=frfbNYv-PoE) on youtube I cannot get my ocean visible as anything but blank white in rendered view. The London eye also has a very rough material and also only shows up as blank white. When I made the ocean in simulation I had to scale it up hugely to correspond to what I have made. Might this be the problem? should I be scaling everything down at this stage instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your lamp's emission strength. Currently it's value is 600. That's too much. Select your Sun lamp and lower the emission strength.